# Why do i get this error?

Tags: java, function

this is the snippet that produces an error saying :

```
')' expected
';' expected
not a statement
cannot find symbol
symbol : variable ActionEvent
```

The snippet :

```
private void jMenuItem5ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    JFileChooser chooseToAdd = new JFileChooser();
    int option = chooseToAdd.showOpenDialog(this);
    if( option == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION ) {
        nameOfAudioFile = chooseToAdd.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();
        //clonejTree1ValueChanged( TreeSelectionEvent evt );
        tester(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt);
    }
}

private void tester(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    System.out.println("tester");
}
```

Is there any syntax error ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line is wrong:

```
tester(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt);
```

Here you should pass an object of the type ActionEvent.

So it should be something like this:

```
tester(evt);
```

Answer (score 5):

This method invocation is wrong:

```
tester(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt);
```

That's trying to declare a parameter, but you need to be passing an argument. I suspect you want:

```
tester(evt);
```

It's important to understand the difference between a method *declaration* (which declares parameters with names and types) and a method *invocation* (which supplies values for those parameters).

As an aside, assuming you're quite new to Java I would recommend *not* starting off with Swing or any other kind of UI. I would suggest you start off writing some simple console apps that let you get to grips with the basic syntax of Java without having to worry about all the complexities introduced by user interfaces.

Comment: thank you !  i was just overlooking the statement . And i am not new to Java

Comment: @Suhail: If you're not new to Java, I don't quite understand why you didn't understand the syntax error. It's a pretty simple statement, and presumably the IDE showed you which line was wrong...

Comment: Does the error _(that i posted in the question)_ actually tell what is the problem ? I didn't understand why this statement is producing error failing to notice the _illegal_ argument

Comment: @Suhail: Well, it says it's "not a statement" which is correct. But I would have expected anyone with any experience in Java to be able to just look at the line and immediately know what's wrong. It's not one of those situations where the code is very complicated and it's hard to work out what's going wrong - the only thing there is the method invocation. Note that you've made the same mistake in the line that's commented out above.

Comment: @ Jon Skeet ok. yes i was trying out the same thing with other functions without noticing the argument.

Answer (score 3):

Call

```
tester(evt);
```

instead of

```
tester(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt);
```

You shouldn't define the type there, it is already known. Method invocation syntax is not the same as method definition.

Answer (score 2):

If you call a method, you don't have to provide the type of the parameter. So in line 6 of the snippet it only should be

```
tester(evt);
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the type definition from

```
tester(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt);
```